# Cannot figure out the meaning of this error

Tags: c++, oop

```
Error   2   error LNK2005: "void __cdecl strCpy(char * &,char * &)" 

(?strCpy@@YAXAAPAD0@Z) already defined in Car.obj   

C:\Users\l1s15bscs0071\Documents\Visual Studio 

2013\Projects\Lab11_task1\Lab11_task1\Honda.obj Lab11_task1
```

The project can be found on this link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bw2cO-zFzAvsR1lIdURmbVJMaTA

Comment: You're probably missing a header include guard meaning you've put strCpy into multiple object files

Comment: @donkopotamus a header guard wouldn't prevent that, an inline function or a separate definition would.

Answer (score 0):

## Problem: Non-static global-namespace function definition in header

The problem is that you define strCpy in the header, and include it multiple times once for Honda.obj and Car.obj, as you include str.h in the both respective .cpp files.

Since the function is not declared static, it will not be instantiated once, but for each inclusion of str.h in each of the .OBJ separately and the linker will encounter multiple definitions of strCpy().

## Solution 1: Mark strCpy static

```
#include<cstring>

static void strCpy(char *& Source, char *& Dest)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Source); i++)
    {
        Dest[i] = Source[i];
    }

    Dest[strlen(Source)] = '\0';
}
```

## Solution 2: Separate declaration and definition across .h and .cpp files

```
// str.h
# pragma once

void strCpy(char *& Source, char *& Dest);

// str.cpp
#include "str.h"

void strCpy(char *& Source, char *& Dest)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(Source); i++)
    {
        Dest[i] = Source[i];
    }

    Dest[strlen(Source)] = '\0';
}
```

## In both cases:

Add `#pragma once` or a non-VS include-guard `#ifndef <key> #define <key> // code #endif // <key>`